# Extract certain part of text beginning with specified characters from strings of text in Excel cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of cells filled with a lot of text. I only need one string from each cell. If you look closely, you will see that all of these contain an NCT number (NCT followed by a string of numbers).

[image]

I want to create a column next to this one that extracts this value (NCT followed by 8 numbers) from the text string. My initial thought was to extract based on position, but the words are in varying positions.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: use `FIND` or `SEARCH`, and `MID`. This is a fairly common Excel problem and there's lots of online resources.

Comment: I have been searching for over an hour and have not been able to produce this output hence why I have posted it onto here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `MID()` & `FIND()` function:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(MID(B3,FIND("NCT",B3),11),"")
```

---

With `MS365` you can spill with one single dynamic array formula:

```
=LET(α, B3:B13, IFERROR(MID(α,FIND("NCT",α),11),""))
```

---

Or, Using `TEXTAFTER()`

```
=IFERROR("NCT"&LEFT(TEXTAFTER(B3:B13,"NCT"),8),"")
```

---